# Wildfly Make a module depends of a EAR/WAR

Tags: module, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm building a product that must be extended by external people of our organization, we don't want the war to be changed by the "external people".

So, our application has the following structure.

- EAR

  - WAR

    - JAR A
    - JAR B
  - extension module defined in jboss-deployment-structure

The extension module is like this

```
<sub-deployment name="A.war">
   <dependencies>
      <module name="extension.module" optional="false">
      </module>
   </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
```

We thought the "external people" could create the "extension.module" module and than add the behavior they want. But to do that they need to add dependencies to the JAR A and JAR B inside the war/ear.
Can you help me solving this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Does extension.module have any external dependencies, or is it only JAR A and JAR B that depend on the module? Or is is that WAR A depends on JAR A, JAR B and extension.module ?

Comment: I solved this using with a different aproach. Instead using depencies with modules i create two wars that depends one of other. WAR A depends on WAR B and vice versa. This way it worked.